# Hyperledger Fabric(First application) + Hyperledger Explorer error

Tags: ssl, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-explorer

I am trying to integrate Explorer 0.3.9 for fabric version 1.4. using my First application sample code (1 peer)
When I start Explorer with "./start.sh" based on the instruction from the GitHub, the error message is below from console.log:

I think it might be a initial connection procedure problem related with SSL. But I can't find it easily.
I have disabled TLS, so actually, I have no idea why I got the error "wrong version number".

I also tried with the config-basic-network.json file

Thanks

```
postgres://hppoc:password@127.0.0.1:5432/fabricexplorer
(node:70471) DeprecationWarning: grpc.load: Use the @grpc/proto-loader module with grpc.loadPackageDefinition instead
E0305 09:27:28.326740427   70471 ssl_transport_security.cc:1227] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number.
E0305 09:27:29.327317682   70471 ssl_transport_security.cc:1227] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number.
E0305 09:27:31.025392003   70471 ssl_transport_security.cc:1227] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number.
2019-03-05T17:27:31.323Z - [31merror[39m: [Remote.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://localhost:7050
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Explorer Error >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
{ Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://localhost:7050
    at checkState (/home/user/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:720:16) connectFailed: true }
Received kill signal, shutting down gracefully
Closed out connections
```

My config.json file of Explorer is as below:

```
{
  "network-configs": {
    "network-1": {
      "version": "1.0",
      "clients": {
        "client-1": {
          "tlsEnable": false,
          "organization": "Org1MSP",
          "channel": "mychannel",
          "credentialStore": {
            "path": "./tmp/credentialStore_Org1/credential",
            "cryptoStore": {
              "path": "./tmp/credentialStore_Org1/crypto"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "channels": {
        "mychannel": {
          "peers": {
            "peer0.org1.example.com": {}
          },
          "connection": {
            "timeout": {
              "peer": {
                "endorser": "6000",
                "eventHub": "6000",
                "eventReg": "6000"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "organizations": {
        "Org1MSP": {
          "mspid": "Org1MSP",
          "fullpath": false,
          "adminPrivateKey": {
            "path": "/home/user/fabric-samples/basic-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore"
          },
          "signedCert": {
            "path": "/home/user/fabric-samples/basic-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts"
          }
        },
        "OrdererMSP": {
          "mspid": "OrdererMSP",
          "adminPrivateKey": {
            "path": "/home/user/fabric-samples/basic-network/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/keystore"
          }
        }
      },
      "peers": {
        "peer0.org1.example.com": {
          "tlsCACerts": {
            "path": "/home/user/fabric-samples/basic-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
          },
          "url": "grpcs://127.0.0.1:7051",
          "eventUrl": "grpcs://127.0.0.1:7053",
          "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org1.example.com"
          }
        }
      },
      "orderers": {
        "orderer.example.com": {
          "url": "grpcs://127.0.0.1:7050"
        }
      }
    },
    "network-2": {}
  },
  "configtxgenToolPath": "/home/user/fabric-samples/bin",
  "license": "Apache-2.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you database setup correctly using the instruction on https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer#database-setup

Then [Fabric Setup](https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer#fabric-network-setup) need to be done

Once all these steps completed with any error then [run explorer network](https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer#run-hyperledger-explorer)

Comment: The procedures you linked are for the "BYFN" sample code. But, I'm trying to do it with 2nd sample code "Writing Your First Application: fabcar" (https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4/fabcar). The fabcar is using "basic-network". So I need to modify the config.json file of HL Explorer.